# Matlab loops in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

For this loop in MATLAB, after the '`if` - `end`' I want to return to the same loop without executing next `i`. More specifically, I want to tell MATLAB to check until `check(i)` is different from `0`.

```
for i = 1:length(numDate)
    check(i)=any(Dates == numDate(i));
    if check(i) == 0
        numDate(i) = numDate(i)-1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the number of iterations of a `for` loop once it is decided. Use `while` loop for such a case.

```
k=1; %I replaced the loop variable with k because i (and j) are reserved for imag no.s
while k<=length(numDate)
   if any(Dates == numDate(k)) == 0
        numDate(k) = numDate(k)-1;
   else k=k+1;  %increment only if the condition is not satisfied
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `break`

```
for i = 1:length(numDate)
  check(i)=any(Dates == numDate(i));
    if check(i) == 0
       numDate(i) = numDate(i)-1;
    else  
       break
    end
end
```